# Loop a loop inside a loop by simplifying

Tags: c#, loops, combinations

I've been trying to simplify the following by putting it into a loop..

```
int A0 = 0, A1 = 0, A2 = 0;

for (A0 = 0; A0 < nums.Length; A0++)
{
    for (A1 = 0; A1 < nums.Length; A1++)
    {
        for (A2 = 0; A2 < nums.Length; A2++)
        {
            string ss = nums[A0] + nums[A1] + nums[A2];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { ss });
        }
    }
}
```

like A0, A1 and A2, i need to go until A75. I can get the result if i nest like the above. But how can i put it on a loop..??

I tried this one:

```
int[] A = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    for (A[i] = 0; A[i] < nums.Length; A[i]++)
    {
        string ss = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < A.Length; j++) ss += nums[A[i]];
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { ss });
    }
}
```

But it will perform only like..

```
int A0 = 0, A1 = 0, A2 = 0;
for (A0 = 0; A0 < nums.Length; A0++)
{
    string ss = nums[A0] + nums[A1] + nums[A2];
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { ss });
}
for (A1 = 0; A1 < nums.Length; A1++)
{
    string ss = nums[A0] + nums[A1] + nums[A2];
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { ss });
}
for (A2 = 0; A2 < nums.Length; A2++)
{
    string ss = nums[A0] + nums[A1] + nums[A2];
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { ss });
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are trying to solve ?

Comment: you need 2 dimensional arrays A[75, nums.Length]

Comment: Trying to take all the possible combinations, when the no. of digits required and numbers used are passed as parameters..

Comment: You're cross-joining a list with itself 75 times?  What is the purpose?  You realize that will give you `nums.Length ^ 75` rows, right?.  Even with only two elements that's over 377,789,320,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 rows.

Comment: I've tried 2 dimensional arrays. but no luck

Comment: I'm not actually trying to put all those on datagrid rows Mr. Stanley. Im putting on datagrid just to analyse the initial results with low numbers. Then after that i need the final result for something else

Comment: Note there are many questions on generating combinations/permutations in with variety of approaches already. Please clarify why you need this particular way of writing the code and what type of improvements you are looking for.

Comment: Besides all those combinations and permutations solutions, what i'm asking is just the way to loop inside loop. I dont want something made by someone else, cauz while doing from scratch, u may learn and get something new

Comment: Yeah, but you're talking about an algorithm that might take upwards of 40,000 days to run! That's if you can do a million iterations per second, which is doubtful.

Comment: OK, it may take that long. But pls someone tell me a way to put at least 5 or 6 nestings on a loop..

Comment: Well. I already know a solution. That is to put a loop for repeating the code like above to repeat until 75, copy it to clipboard and paste it to some method. That way i can get the result. But I want to learn nesting by loop..

Comment: There's not a built-in syntax to nest loops.  If you can explain better what you're trying to achieve maybe there's a better way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr. Stanley. That's the answer i've been looking for. No way to Nest Loop..

Comment: @DonBoitnott I believe this is might be what we on Code Review would call "example code", and "code not written", which is off-topic there. We also have had [similar questions in the past](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36300/31562)

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent to

```
public void DoNestedThings()
{
    for(var A0 = 0; A0 < _max; A0 ++)
    {
        //...
        for(var i5 = 0; i5 < _max; i5++)
        {
            DoThing(new List<int>{i0, ..., i5});
        }
    }
}
```

Would be:

```
private void DoNestedThings(int depth, Stack<int> indexes)
{
    if(depth == 0)
    {
        DoThing(indexes);
        return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < _max; i++)
    {
        indexes.Push(i);
        DoNestedThings(depth-1, indexes);
        indexes.Pop();
    }
}

public void DoNestedThings()
{
    DoNestedThings(5, new Stack<int>());
}
```

This replaces nested loops with a single loop, but then uses recursion to enter into that loop multiple times. Each time the `DoNestedThings` method is called with `depth` > 0, you enter into another loop.

(Note the order of the indexes passed to `DoThing` will be reversed)

Comment: Excellent one... Recurse until it reaches its depth and return result to the first calll..

Answer (score 1):

See [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) for how to write a method that can compute the Cartesian Product of a number of collections not known at compile time, which is exactly the problem you're trying to solve.

You can then create the collection of collections dynamically by simply using `Repeat`:

```
var query = Enumerable.Repeat(nums, 75)
    .CartesianProduct()
    .Select(combination => combination.Sum());
```

Of course, the size of such a query is going to be [pretty large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437557/loop-a-loop-inside-a-loop-by-simplifying/28437811#comment45205165_28437557).  This approach is going to leverage deferred execution to allow you to compute each result as you go, rather than computing every single result before giving you any, but if you actually try to compute a significant percentage of the values (or all of them) you're going to be waiting for...a long time.